# PHP return data from anonymous in file

Tags: php, file, return, arguments, anonymous-function

I have seen a file that looks kind of like this:

`my-file.php`

```
<?php
return function($some, $args) {
  return array(
    'foo' => 'my first template variable',
    'bar' => 'my second template variable'
  );
};
```

It's an anonymous function that return data and it is somehow fetched and used somewhere else.

How can I fetch data from a file that looks like this?

*I've been searching and looked into other questions but I did not find anything like it.*

Comment: `$callable = require 'my-file.php';`? Yes, it's not pretty :P.

Comment: @JonStirling That might actually work, but how can I send arguments to it?

Comment: You call it the same way as other anonymous functions, `$data = $callable($arg1, $arg2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the relevant documentation can be found on the [include document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and the [anonymous function document](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

To summarise, included / required files can return values. These can then be assigned to variables.

In this case you could do the following:

```
$callable = require 'my-file.php';
```

This would assign the anonymous function to `$callable` at which point you can treat it as a standard closure (because that's what it is) and call it as you would a function:

```
$callable($anyargs, $needed);
```

Which in this case would return the data in the array.